# git hook and ssh on server

Tags: ssh, python, git, tty

I have a git repo on a server. I would like to run a update hook on this when a push is done.

I am unable to get git revlist or take any information from the user because i can't enable tty.

I have written the hook in python. I would like it so I can retrieve commit history from my local repo and use that information in the process of my update hook, which checks for pattern in commits.

the problem i am having is that when i run the command from my script it is being executed on my server.

Please any advice would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running this in your post-receive hook script?

```
GIT_DIR=/path_to_repo/project.git git log branch_you_just_pushed
```

are your trying to do something like [Using Git to manage a web site](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto)?